# How pytest knows that a function argument is fixture?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytest, fixtures

According to pytest Documentation:

fixtures are implemented in a modular manner, as each fixture name triggers a fixture function which can itself use other fixtures.

```
import pytest

@pytest.yield_fixture
def passwd():
    with open("/etc/passwd") as f:
        yield f.readlines()

def test_has_lines(passwd):
    assert len(passwd) >= 1
```

For the above code, function test_has_lines has an input argument "passwd" and pytest will load it from generated value of passwd().

How pytest knows that an argument (in this case passwd) is fixture?

I am more interested in the internal working of it.

Comment: Because the argument name `passwd` matches the name of the fixture. If you change `passwd` to `password` it will break (I assume)

Comment: How pytest detects that it need to search that argument in the fixture?

Comment: That's answered in the pytest code itself; you would have to look there for details, but presumably, it keeps a list of fixtures, and then scans each test function for the parameter names, and tries to match those with the fixture names.

Comment: @HarshitAgarwal `import inspect; inspect.signature(passwd).parameters`. pytest knows that the `passwd` fixture exist either because the decorator you use inserts it in some mapping, or by looking up all imported modules. Python is quite dynamic so having access to stuff like all imported classes, names of parameters etc is not hard to do at all.